# Out of memory with Tomcat and Datastore Remote Accessor

Tags: java, google-app-engine, tomcat, google-cloud-datastore, remote-access

We are developing a web application that run on a Tomcat in a Compute Engine environment. We exploit Google Datastore as DB and we connect to the DB with Datastore Remote Accessor.
The application is really simple and it's working fine, however after a certain time without a specific reason the CPU usage increase drastically from 0 to 100% and Tomcat gives an out of memory error. From the logs there is no activity but after a certain time the JVM fails and tomcat gives out of memory error.

We are quite new in using the datastore remote accessor api to connect to the datastore from a compute engine machine. For this reason, We were wondering if there is some best practices to follow or if someone has already got the same problem.

Thanks
Simone

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ajp-apr-8009-AsyncTimeout"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AsyncFileHandlerWriter-856419764"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Keep-Alive-Timer"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]

Comment: You can dump the memory onto the filesystem, using jdk tools (jmap). Then you can use a memory analyzer like eclipse mat. Its reports will point you to the problem most of the time,...

Comment: Thanks I'll try that